# Insert query fails abruptly because of document validation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using document validation in MongoDB which is supposed to validate the datatypes of the attributes of documents which I insert into the `users` collection. Here are the commands which I have executed in the exact same sequence

```
> db.createCollection("users");
{ "ok" : 1 }

> db.runCommand({
...  collMod: "users",
...  validator: {
...    $and : [
...      { "nm" : { $type : "string" }},
...      { "mob" : { $type : "int" }},
...    ]
...  },
...  validationAction: "error",
...  validationLevel: "strict"
... });
{ "ok" : 1 }

> db.users.insertOne(
  {
...  "nm" : "foo",
...  "eml" : "foo@gmail.com",
...  "mob" : 12345,
...  "isa" : true,
...  "blod" : "O+",
...  "sid" : 1,
...  "cid" : 1,
...  "aid" : 1,
...  "add" : "bar",
...  "dob" : "16-Sep-1992"
...});
```

But as soon as I run the last `insertOne` command, it fails the document validation and prints the following output.

```
2017-01-04T18:27:16.824+0530 E QUERY    [main] WriteError: Document failed validation :
WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 121,
    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
    "op" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("586cf12c5a37c6beeeb15940"),
        "nm" : "foo",
        "eml" : "foo@gmail.com",
        "mob" : 12345,
        "isa" : true,
        "blod" : "O+",
        "sid" : 1,
        "cid" : 1,
        "aid" : 1,
        "add" : "bar",
        "dob" : "16-Sep-1992"
    }
});
WriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:469:48
Bulk/mergeBatchResults@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:836:49
Bulk/executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:906:13
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1150:21
DBCollection.prototype.insertOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:242:9
@(shell):1:1
```

I am trying to figure out what if it is the problem with my validator or the data that I am inserting but couldn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `"number"` instead of `"int"` in your document validation :

run

```
db.runCommand({
   collMod:"users",
   validator:{
      $and:[
         {
            "nm":{
               $type:"string"
            }
         },
         {
            "mob":{
               $type:"number"
            }
         },

      ]
   },
   validationAction:"error",
   validationLevel:"strict"
})
```

and it should work fine

Comment: I just figured out that the number with I was trying to enter actually goes in as float and that I need to use `NumberInt(12345)` for the mobile number entry which I am using. But your approach seems correct.